# Database repository comparison and/or update in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, repository-pattern, android-livedata

I'm new to android programming and want to try to learn best practices.  My first app I'm building is a podcast app to display podcasts from an rss feed and play them.  What I have so far *is* working, but I know I can make it work better.

I'm using a Room Database with a Repository pattern, which might be overkill because I probably don't need to persist the podcast list across app death if I'm just going to re-parse the feed on startup.  In my repository class I'm calling my FetchRSS class to do the network call in the `init{ }` block which returns a `List<Podcast>`.

I know I'm not doing something right.

In my PodcastDao, I have to use `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` because the database already exists and I get an SQL error 1555 regarding duplicate primary key ids.  Logically, it'd be better to have a check to see if the entry to be added is already in the database, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.  Or, illogically, clear the database on app death, but then why bother with a database at all.  Ideally, I'd like to have a swipe to update function(even if the RSS only updates at most twice a week), but I'm not sure how best to do that.

If anyone has any thoughts about improving this, or a good book for learning android, I'd be all ears.
Thank you so much to everyone who takes the time to look at this!

**PodcastDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface PodcastDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM podcast")  // get everything from the database
    fun getPodcasts(): LiveData<List<Podcast>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM podcast WHERE id=(:id)") // get the specific podcast
    fun getPodcast(id: String): LiveData<Podcast?>

//    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
//    fun addPodcasts(podcasts: LiveData<List<Podcast>>)
//    this causes a build error with the generated PodcastDao.java file
// logcat error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun addPodcast(podcast: Podcast)
}
```

**PodcastRepository.kt**

```
class PodcastRepository private constructor(context: Context) {

private lateinit var podcasts: List<Podcast>

    init {

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {

            podcasts = FetchRSS().fetchRss() // executes on Dispatchers.IO and returns parsed rss List<Podcast>

            // this seems silly to add them one at a time, especially since the list is rather large
            for (pod in podcasts) {
                addPodcast(pod)
            }
            //it seems a better choice to dump the full list into the database at once
            //however I can't figure out how to put the List<Podcast> into a LiveData<List<Podcast>> object
            //or maybe I'm misunderstanding something about LiveData<>
            //addPodcasts(podcasts)
        }
    }

    suspend fun addPodcast(podcast: Podcast){
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            podcastDao.addPodcast(podcast)
        }

// this needs to receive the LiveData<List<Podcast>>, or a List<Podcast> and cram it into LiveData<>?
//    suspend fun addPodcasts(podcasts: LiveData<List<Podcast>>) {
//        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
//            podcastDao.addPodcasts(podcasts)
//        }
//    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun addPodcasts(podcasts: LiveData<List<Podcast>>)
```

should be

```
fun addPodcasts(podcasts: <List<Podcast>>)
```

So, now you can call `podcastDao.addPodcasts(podcasts)` (where `podcasts` is of type `List<Podcast>>`) from inside your repository instead of inserting them one by one through a for loop.

You cannot insert a LiveData into Room, only objects marked with `@Entity`. You can, however, have a query return a LiveData with a List of those entities. You can also return just a List as well.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Just to be sure, I deleted my database and recreated it using `addPodcasts(podcasts)`